# Intersection of multiple arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, intersection

I have a view defined as:

```
 CREATE VIEW View1 AS 
 SELECT Field1, Field2, array_agg(Field3) AS AggField 
 FROM Table1 
 GROUP BY Field1, Field2;
```

What I would like to do is get the intersection of the arrays in `AggField` with something like:

```
SELECT intersection(AggField) FROM View1 WHERE Field2 = 'SomeValue';
```

Is this at all possible, or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The closest thing to an array intersection that I can think of is this:

```
select array_agg(e)
from (
    select unnest(a1)
    intersect
    select unnest(a2)
) as dt(e)
```

This assumes that `a1` and `a2` are single dimension arrays with the same type of elements. You could wrap that up in a function something like this:

```
create function array_intersect(a1 int[], a2 int[]) returns int[] as $$
declare
    ret int[];
begin
    -- The reason for the kludgy NULL handling comes later.
    if a1 is null then
        return a2;
    elseif a2 is null then
        return a1;
    end if;
    select array_agg(e) into ret
    from (
        select unnest(a1)
        intersect
        select unnest(a2)
    ) as dt(e);
    return ret;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then you could do things like this:

```
=> select array_intersect(ARRAY[2,4,6,8,10], ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
 array_intersect 
-----------------
 {6,2,4,10,8}
(1 row)
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee any particular order in the returned array but you can fix that if you care about it. Then you could create your own aggregate function:

```
-- Pre-9.1
create aggregate array_intersect_agg(
    sfunc    = array_intersect,
    basetype = int[],
    stype    = int[],
    initcond = NULL
);

-- 9.1+ (AFAIK, I don't have 9.1 handy at the moment
-- see the comments below.
create aggregate array_intersect_agg(int[]) (
    sfunc = array_intersect,
    stype = int[]
);
```

And now we see why `array_intersect` does funny and somewhat kludgey things with NULLs. We need an initial value for the aggregation that behaves like the universal set and we can use NULL for that (yes, this smells a bit off but I can't think of anything better off the top of my head).

Once all this is in place, you can do things like this:

```
> select * from stuff;
    a    
---------
 {1,2,3}
 {1,2,3}
 {3,4,5}
(3 rows)

> select array_intersect_agg(a) from stuff;
 array_intersect_agg 
---------------------
 {3}
(1 row)
```

Not exactly simple or efficient but maybe a reasonable starting point and better than nothing at all.

Useful references:

- [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)
- [create aggregate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html)
- [create function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)
- [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)
- [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

Comment: on postgres 9.1 the agg function needs to be like """CREATE AGGREGATE array_intersect_agg(integer[]) (
  SFUNC=array_intersect,
  STYPE=int4[]
);"""

Comment: @Rescommunes: Is the 9.1 version I added correct? I don't have a 9.1 handy to test it myself.

Comment: yes its good. Also, not sure if 9.1+ is where the difference is or not (could be earlier).

Comment: Alternatively: install the intarray extension which provides an intersection operator (`&`)

Comment: what is dt(e) ?

Comment: @smaiakov That's an alias for the derived table so that the query will know that a "table" named `dt` refers that the UNION and that it's "column" is named `e`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me.  This is how I fixed it.

```
create or replace function array_intersect(a1 int[], a2 int[]) returns int[] as $$
declare
  ret int[];
begin
  -- RAISE NOTICE 'a1 = %', a1;
  -- RAISE NOTICE 'a2 = %', a2;
  if a1 is null then
    -- RAISE NOTICE 'a1 is null';
    return a2;
  -- elseif a2 is null then
  --    RAISE NOTICE 'a2 is null';
  --    return a1;
  end if;
  if array_length(a1,1) = 0 then
    return '{}'::integer[];
  end if;
  select array_agg(e) into ret
  from (
    select unnest(a1)
    intersect
    select unnest(a2)
  ) as dt(e);
  if ret is null then
    return '{}'::integer[];
  end if;
  return ret;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bit late to answer this question but maybe somebody will need it so I decided to share something I wrote cause did not found any ready solution for intersection of any number of arrays. So here it is. This function receives array of arrays, if it is only single array, function returns first array, if there are 2 arrays function intersects 2 arrays and returns result, if it is more that 2 arrays, function takes intersection of 2 first arrays, stores it in some  variable and loops through all other arrays, intersect each next array with stored result and stores result in variable. if result is null it exists with null. In the and the variable that stores array with interacted data returned from the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_intersected(iarray bigint[][])
  RETURNS bigint[] AS
$BODY$
    declare out_arr bigint[]; set1 bigint[]; set2 bigint[];
    BEGIN
        --RAISE NOTICE '%', array_length(iarray, 1);
        if array_length(iarray, 1) = 1 then
            SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(iarray[1:1])) into out_arr;
        elseif array_length( iarray, 1) = 2 then
            set1 := iarray[1:1];
            set2 := iarray[2:2];
            SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(set1) INTERSECT SELECT unnest(set2))into out_arr;
        elseif array_length(iarray, 1) > 2 then
            set1 := iarray[1:1];
            set2 := iarray[2:2];
            --exit if no common numbers exists int 2 first arrays
            SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(set1) INTERSECT SELECT unnest(set2))into out_arr;
            if out_arr = NULL then
                EXIT;
                END IF;
            FOR i IN 3 .. array_upper(iarray, 1)
            LOOP
               set1 := iarray[i:i];
               SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(set1) INTERSECT SELECT unnest(out_arr))into out_arr;
               if out_arr = NULL then
                EXIT;
                   END IF;
            END LOOP;
        end if;

    return out_arr;

    END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

**Here is the code to validate it works.**

```
select array_intersected(array[[1, 2]]::bigint[][]);

select array_intersected(array[[1, 2],[2, 3]]::bigint[][]);

select array_intersected(array[[1, 2],[2, 3], [2, 4]]::bigint[][]);

select array_intersected(array[[1, 2, 3, 4],[null, null, 4, 3], [3, 1, 4, null]]::bigint[][]);
```