# Postgresql find intersections across n arrays

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intersection of multiple arrays in PostGreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020264/intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-postgresql)

I'm trying to identify the common elements across multiple (>2) arrays in a Pg 9.2 database. The data is structured as:

ID   Title   Array 
1    title1  {a,b,c,d,...}
2    title2  {z,y,a,d,...}
3    title3  {d,a,p,q,...}
n    ...     ...

From the example above, the SELECT should return {a,d} as the common elements of each array.

I've got this working for 2 arrays as a test case using:

...
select array_agg(e)
from (
    select unnest(arr1) from cte_1
    intersect
    select unnest(arr2) from cte_2
) as dt(e)),
...

But havent been able to get it working correctly with RECURSIVE CTEs. Found some useful examples online and in various Joe Celko books/snippets.

The best I've been able to come up with was this post using custom functions:

[Intersection of multiple arrays in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020264/intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-postgresql)

but it seems there should be a way do accomplish this with a RECURSIVE or other technique.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need intersection between null-free `int[]` only, this might be useful. Sorry if it's not the case, but you didn't make it clear in your question.

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]::int[] & ARRAY[3,4,5]::int[] & ARRAY[1,3,5,7]::int[] as intersection;
intersection 
--------------
{3}
(1 row)
```

Here's the complete [intarray contrib module documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html).

**EDIT**:
[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756871/postgres-function-to-return-the-intersection-of-2-arrays) with possibly useful answers. I'd try what user [depesz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80168/depesz) suggests first.