# Intersection of multiple text arrays: ERROR: array value must start with "{"

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, intersection, postgresql-8.4

I'm attemping to get the functions in this question to work: [Intersection of multiple arrays in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020264/intersection-of-multiple-arrays-in-postgresql)

Unlike that question, I want to intersect text arrays instead of integer arrays.  I've modified both functions accordingly.  Base array intersect function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_intersect(a1 text[], a2 text[]) RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE
    ret text[];
BEGIN
    IF a1 is null THEN
        return a2;
    ELSEIF a2 is null THEN
        RETURN a1;
    END IF;
    SELECT array_agg(e) INTO ret
    FROM (
        SELECT unnest(a1)
        INTERSECT
        SELECT unnest(a2)
    ) AS dt(e);
    RETURN ret;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Aggregate function definition:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE utility.array_intersect_agg(
    sfunc    = array_intersect,
    basetype = text[],
    stype    = text[],
    initcond = NULL
);
```

I get the error "ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
SQL state: 22P02" when I try to run the following code:

```
SELECT array_intersect_agg(test)
  FROM(
    SELECT ARRAY['A','B','C'] test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ARRAY['A','C'] test
    ) a
```

What needs to change in order for these functions to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createaggregate.html):

> *initial_condition*
>
> The initial setting for the state value. This must be a string
>   constant in the form accepted for the data type state_data_type. If
>   not specified, the state value starts out null.

So the aggregate declaration should look like this:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_intersect_agg(
    sfunc    = array_intersect,
    basetype = text[],
    stype    = text[]
);
```