PostgreSQL: Intersection within a table
I have a table in the form
Column A: String
Column B: Integer
These are the only columns and they both form the PK.
Sample data:



Column A
Column B




'abc'
1


'abc'
2


'abc'
3


'def'
1


'def'
3


'ghi'
3



I need a view that gives me the intersection of column B for all values of A from the query.
I have already asked a few AIs, but without any meaningful results.
Expectation: select A, B from myView where A in ('abc','def','ghi')
which returns B=3 since 3 is the intersection of the values of B for all values of A from the query.
The best result would be (to be able to continue joining)



Column A
Column B




'abc'
3


'def'
3


'ghi'
3



No extension should be necessary for this.
Thanks for your help and ideas :)

With intersection, do you mean "3" is the biggest value for all occurrences of that specific value from your first column?
You could just use GROUPBY Column A and use MAX for Column B in that case,

what if your table get updated, and now has a new row:
Column A:  'jkl'
Coliumn B:   4
How will your output table look?

@Beowolve Not the highest value, but the intersection. If I select by A, 3 is the only value that occurs in all result rows for each value of A.

@hassaanmustafa It is unlikely that a new column will be added. But in this case, it does not have to be included in the view.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7020264/1048572 might be relevant, though you'd first have to array_agg(b) … GROUP BY a. It could then compute the intersection of {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3} and {3} to {3}.

Not sure if I understood you correct, but I guess you want something like this:
SELECT colA, colB
FROM yourTable
WHERE colB IN (
    SELECT colB
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY colB
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colA) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT colA) FROM yourTable)
);

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/24RniAr72kNddd995pysVb/0

Your fiddle works well, but with my real data I get no result
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8SMyjqhCJi5GDtT457uLXk/0

I would guess that there isn't a perfect intersection, based on your response above '... But in this case, it does not have to be included in the view. ' it seems you are actually looking for the maximum overlap — the most As with matching Bs.

I think the most straighforward query to get the desired result would be
SELECT array_agg(a), b
FROM example
GROUP BY b
HAVING array_agg(a) @> ARRAY['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];

(online demo)
however that returns one row with an array of all the a values for that intersected b, not multiple rows. Maybe you don't need those though, in particular if you already know the a values you're looking for? Otherwise you'd have to write
SELECT a, b
FROM example
WHERE b = (
  SELECT b
  FROM example
  GROUP BY b
  HAVING array_agg(a) @> ARRAY['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
);

(online demo)

That won't work for my application. I need this for a view that I can use to make any selection.

select A, B from myView where A in ('abc','def','ghi') is not possible. You cannot do intersection by adding a where clause outside of the view.

I think addresses what you are looking for which is the maximum overlap: As with the most matching Bs.
WITH overlap AS (
  SELECT b
  FROM example
  GROUP BY b
  ORDER BY COUNT(a) DESC, b ASC
  LIMIT 1 
)
SELECT
  a,
  b
FROM example
WHERE b = (SELECT b FROM overlap);

fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3LyhsXEv6xSSfb1JRVbjNV/4
with your sample data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aee9RnDbbcs5wfKXJHwwVw/5

I think, it is not possible
select A, B from myView where A in ('abc','def','ghi')

Possible
select a,b from myView where ar @> ARRAY['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

See example
create view vt as 
(
select a,b,array_agg(an) ar 
from (
  select t1.a,t1.b,t2.a an
  from test t1
  left join test t2 on t2.b=t1.b 
  )data
group by a,b
);

select a,b from vt
where ar @> ARRAY['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
order by b, a

Output is



a
b




a-1
3


a-2
3


abc
3


def
3


ghi
3


a-1
4


abc
4


def
4


ghi
4



with test data as
CREATE TABLE test (a text, b int);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ('abc', 1),  ('abc', 2),  ('abc', 3),  ('abc', 4),
  ('def', 1),  ('def', 3),  ('def', 4),
  ('a-1', 2),  ('a-1', 3),  ('a-1', 4),
  ('a-2', 2),  ('a-2', 3),--  ('a-2', 4),
  ('ghi', 3),  ('ghi', 4);

Your sample data is quite poor. Maybe you need some like this:
more strict query
select a,b from vt
where ar @> ARRAY['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
  and array_position(ARRAY['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],a)>0
order by b, a

Demo
With your real data fiddle
